# PHP MySQL statement returns nothing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently developing an application that will be communicating with a database via a PHP service I have written.

The service I am having problems with is one that should look for a row or rows in a table based on a search string from the users.

The PHP below is designed to recieve a GET request with a variable of "name" which will be the data the SQL query uses. I cannot see anything wrong with my code however the rows returned from a search is always 0.

```
// checks for the post data
if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    $name = '%' . $_GET['name'] . '%';

    // get a list of products from the database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE $name");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $products = array();
            $products["id"] = $row["id"];
            $products["name"] = $row["name"];
            $products["type"] = $row["type"];
            $products["price"] = $row["price"];
            $products["photo"] = $row["photo"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // products node
            $response["products"] = array();

            array_push($response["products"], $products);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no products found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No products found";

            // echo no products JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no products found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Search Complete... No products found";

        // echo no products JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I have an entry in the table it is looking at and a name of "crisps", so when I send a get request with data of say "cr" i would expect to see that entry in the results, however it returns 0 rows.

Then whats even stranger is when I run the SQL below directly against my database it actually pulls back the correct record.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE "%cr%"
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Note that all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). You also need to escape `%` and `_` in `$_GET['name']`.

Comment: Off-Topic Help: Your going to have more issues after you solve this. See: `$result = mysql_query();` then you have `$result = mysql_fetch_array()` but then you use `$row["price"]`. `$row` will be undefined and `$result` will contain an array of arrays. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you need to add the quotes `'`   to your `'$name'`

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '$name'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't wrap the value with single quote, remember that it is a string literal.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '$name'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)